# jquery ui tabs dynamically added tab id

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I have a page which uses jquery ui tabs. 
In this page, i need to add and remove tabs dynamically. The functionality for that is implemented. Now, everytime I add a new tab, jquery generates an id for the tab automatically. Somethig like `ui-tabs-1`, `ui-tabs-3` etc. I need to know, is there any way that I can get the index of this id. (the **1**, **3** that are appended). Because, I need to use the id inside the tab for some functioanlity and with dynamic addition and deletion, I cannit get the id of the tab that easily.

Comment: some fiddler or some hint how you getting the ID would be nice...

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/vonDy2791/yHGaC/1/)** ? Hope it helps

```
$(function () {
    $("#tabs").tabs({
        collapsible: true
    });
});

$("#tabs ul li").on('click', function () {
    var indx = $("li").index(this);
    alert(indx);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you may handle this event

```
$( ".selector" ).tabs({
  create: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```